# QByteArray to Int conversion

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to convert a `QByteArray` into an `int` with the following code :

```
int byteArrayToint(const QByteArray &ba, QDataStream::ByteOrder byteOrder)
{
    int val = 0;
    QDataStream stream(ba);
    stream.setByteOrder(byteOrder);
    stream >> val;
    return val;
}
```

Then in the main function :

```
    ....
    QByteArray ba;
    ba[0]=0x20;
    ba[1]=0x17;

    for(int i(0); i < ba.size(); i++)
        qInfo() << QString("0x%1").arg((int)ba.at(i), 2, 16);

    qInfo() << "date =" << byteArrayToint(ba, QDataStream::BigEndian);
    ...
```

And the output is :

```
"0x20"
"0x17"
date = 0
```

But if i use QByteArray("Hello") instead of the preivous one it gives the expected result :

```
"0x48"
"0x65"
"0x6c"
"0x6c"
"0x6f"
date = 1214606444
```

I cannot find where the mistake is so far. I know methods using bits shifting work well but i would like to understand why i don't get the same result with Qt classes.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Check the stream `status()` after you read from it, I'll guess you'll get "read past the end" status.

Comment: I guess the int your're using is 4 byte and you only put 2 bytes in the QByteArray!?

Comment: @Mat You are right. i did not pay attention to this point. After i added zeros according to Endianess, it works as expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
stream >> val;
```

you'reading `sizeof(int)` bytes from the stream into the variable val.

Given that `sizeof(int)` is 4, whatever byte array sized at least four bytes is ok to yeld some int value (the remaining bytes will be ignored).