# QByteArray to int always give 0

Tags: qt, qbytearray

I try to send data throw qtcpsocket and use QByteArray. I send previosly size of data and try convert to int like this [QByteArray to Int conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47554028/qbytearray-to-int-conversion).
But always get 0. Code convertion example:

```
QString ss = "bca";
int aaa;
QByteArray b;
QDataStream stream(&b, QIODevice::ReadWrite);

stream << ss.toUtf8().size();
stream >> aaa;
```

In this example aaa is always 0, but ss.toUtf8().size() isnt. What im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QString ss = "bca";
int aaa;
QByteArray b;
QDataStream stream(&b, QIODevice::ReadWrite);

stream << ss.toUtf8().size();
stream.device().seek(0); // add this code
stream >> aaa;
```

The inner pointer of QByteArray is at the end, so nothing can be read.