# PyQt5, QByteArray slices return str, how to get bytes or int?

Tags: python, pyqt5

The closest match to my question is [a Qt example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47554028/qbytearray-to-int-conversion), not a PyQt5 example.

I am using a QByteArray in PyQt5 to receive packets of data over a QSerialPort.  My system is real-time.  The host and peripheral are not perfectly synchronized.  I could get a partial data packet read in one timer cycle.  So I have devised a data packet format which gives the payload length in byte 1, as an unsigned 8-bit integer.  If I don't receive the expected number of bytes in one cycle, I know to keep reading on the next cycle.  The payload also contains binary content, not ASCII.

Today I was surprised to discover that QByteArray[slice] and QByteArray.at(value) return Python **string** objects.  I simply want the numeric value of a single byte, so that I can check my payload length.

Is there a straightforward way to accomplish this?  This works, but it strikes me as insanely complicated:

`length = int.from_bytes(bytes(packet[1], encoding="ascii"), byteorder="big")`

I have to wonder whether I've missed some useful method(s) in either the Python standard library or in PyQt5.QByteArray.

(Environment details: PyQt 5.9.2 and Python 3.8.3 in an Anaconda virtual environment, running on Ubuntu 20.04.  None of these details should matter, but I provide them for completeness.  Eventually I will need cross-platform functionality, and I've achieved it with earlier versions of the software I'm building now.)

Comment: QByteArrays can be converted to python strings using `bytes(byteArray).decode()`, so you can try to convert that value, then just use `int()`.

Comment: You could show the code that sends the information, and the content of the QByteArray.